# Windows "type into list view" timer customization

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

When the cursor is in windows explorer (the file manager, not the browser), pressing a number of keys selects the filename starting with these characters. This is set by "folder options->view->when typing into list view.."

However, there seems to be an internal timer linked with the typed characters. If you don't press any key for about 1 sec, the typed string is ignored and typing new characters starts a new search (much like an invisible version of firefox's search box)

Is there a registry key that can modify the duration of this timer ??

Answer (score 2):

From *Default List-View Message Processing* in the Windows SDK.

> **Message Processing**
>
> The following table describes the window message processing performed by a list-view control.
>
> **Message Processing performed**
>
> `WM_CHAR` Searches for a list-view item that begins with the specified character and, if the item is found, selects and sets the focus to the item.
>
> Multiple characters received within a time-out interval, **currently fixed at one second**, are concatenated, and the list-view control searches for an item that begins with the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any registry mods for this, but [Listary](http://www.listary.com) effectively eliminates Explorer's type-to-find timeout, while greatly extending its functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, listary performs search, instead of selection, which is already possible by a setting in "folder options" (although the search listary performs is indeed faster).
However, most of the time, when you are in a folder, you need to select a file that is already visible. Typing into a list view is not a search method, but a faster alternative to using the mouse, or pressing the arrow keys multiple times.